# Telegram bot for a periodic bulletin

Tags: c#, bots, push, telegram

I need to create in .NET 5 with C# a Telegram bot as in the subject.

I'm relatively new to bots (some work with Skype, Telegram) but until now experience with bots where the user writes something and obtain an answer.

In this case the user when subscribed should not see a textbox where to write, but only a button where to pause/restart the pushing mechanism.

When push is activated, the user should receive once a day a bulletin (in practice, an image and some text): no interaction required except the download of a PDF.

I have seen the page https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates, ok very rich infos but also googling i'm not finding a sample basic code in c# and clearly explained steps in order to create the daily push.

Answer (score 0):

You may need like a scheduler for send/post message daily, You can use Hangfire.

I have used it for my Bot. It have a web UI for managing Jobs.

https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: The problem is not the scheduling, i already know Hangfire, but the c# push code for the bot.

And how to have the interface not as a textbox but as a two state button.

Comment: you may need like a button for control user will enable or disable subscription? https://i.imgur.com/qxco2CI.png

Comment: Yes, i don't want the line where the user can write commands, must be substituted with an on/off button